# How to dynamically select the controller with the same request using Spring WebFlux?

Tags: spring, routes, spring-webflux

I have an application implemented using Spring WebFlux, and the routing is done through RouterFunctions. Now I want the controller selection to be based on some customized class dynamically *in runtime* instead of just static URI pattern or request header, how to do that?

For example: there is a request with path /v1/xyz, today we want to have 60% random requests with that path go to controller A and 40% go to controller B, and tomorrow the percentage will be adjusted to 80% and 20%. So I need a mechanism to *dynamically* decide which controller the same request goes to, how to do that?

Thank you.

Comment: Use something like feature toggles (like [FF4J](https://ff4j.org) or [Togglz](https://www.togglz.org)), which you can let do what you want based on the configuration of said toggles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Spring WebFlux [Functional Endpoints](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web-reactive.html#webflux-fn)

> a lightweight functional programming model in which functions are
> used to route and handle requests

that will give you more flexibility and control comparing to controllers.

```
    @Bean
    RouterFunction<ServerResponse> xyzRoute() {
        return route(POST("/v1/xyz"), req -> handler(req));
    }

    Mono<ServerResponse> handler(ServerRequest serverRequest) {
        return evaluateCondition()
                .flatMap(condition -> {
                    if (Boolean.TRUE.equals(condition)) {
                        retrun handler1(serverRequest);
                    } else {
                        retrun handler2(serverRequest);
                    }
                });
    }

    Mono<ServerResponse> handler1(ServerRequest serverRequest) {
   ...
    }

    Mono<ServerResponse> handler2(ServerRequest serverRequest) {
   ...
    }
```